# Out of memory with still memory

Tags: java, java-8

I'm getting an outOfMemory java heap in my application.
After I check the GC.logs I can see that I'm having minor GC but it is after some time I can see more and more often FullGC´s in the log.

Then when it goes down and gives me the Out of memory, I can see in the dump created and even in the Gc.log that the total heap Xmx memory was actually not consumed.

As I could read Java save % of the memory heap for the old generation section, and once this % it's exceeded throw the out of memory. That could explain why I'm having an out of memory with actually still memory.

Any idea any other case this sort of Out of memory can happens?.

Regards.

Comment: Could be because the system was running low on memory and could not allocate all of the heap

Comment: Not all OutOfMemory errors are the same, and not all mean you ran out of heap, just that you ran out of a memory resource of which there are many. Without seeing the actual error message there is no way to know.

Comment: As I could read Java save % of the memory heap for the old generation section, and once this % it's exceeded throw the out of memory. That could explain why I'm having an out of memory with actually still memory.

Comment: Can you just increase the amount of memory on your system?

Comment: It has 2gb already, when at the beginning was 512mb which it should be more than enough.

Comment: without *actual* logs - its impossible to say. attach the relevant parts as well.

Comment: can you increase the heap size with -Xmx flag? Have you done that?

Comment: Sure xms 512 xmx 2gb was set